# How to make double "if" condition in a countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript code:

```js
function t5am() {
// Set the date we're counting down to
// Year, Month ( 0 for January ), Day, Hour, Minute, Second, , Milliseconds
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
//::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
//::::::::::::              5:00 AM                  ::::::::::::
//::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
//                                   (AAAA,MM,DD,HH,mm,S));
var countDownDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,05,29,12,00,00));

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function () {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    // GMT/UTC Adjustment at the end of the function. 0 = GMT/UTC+0; 1 = GMT/UTC+1.
    var distance = countDownDate - now - (3600000 * 1);

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("t5am")){
        ele.innerHTML = (days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> "
            + minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />")
    }
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("t5am")) {
            ele.innerHTML = "<p class='live-text'>Live</p> ";
        }
            if (distance + 7200000 < 0){
              ele.innerHTML = "Ended";  
            }
    }
}, 1000);
}
t5am()
```

It is a counter that works fine for me, but now I want to do a double "if" function.

When the counter reaches zero, then it shows "Started".
I need that in addition to that, after 2 hours after "Started", it shows "Ended"

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to start the counter after 2 hours if its already zero or you want to check both or either conditions ?

Comment: It's like a super easy task really. `if (distance + «2 hours» < 0) {` just adapt

Comment: once inside the `if` start a `setTimeout(function, 2*60*60*1000)` where `function`, similar to what you wrote, sets t5am to "Ended".

Comment: oh, don't forget to `clearInterval(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `how` you can do this:

Just need add `two` more hours to your current time which i have done below and then check if `distance` + `twoHours` < 0 to show '**Ended**' Message

**Also,** you have to `clearInterval(x)` as well i will leave that for you to clear when you want after the condition have been met and it is ended.

**Remember:** Its **NOT** ideal to use `setTimeout` for this because if the user leave the page and come page the `setTimeout` `funtion` will start from 2 hours again which is not ideal in your case you want to stop it exactly after 2 hours to when its was started which will be in real time regardless of user staying on the browser / screen or not.

Just to make some correction on using `innerHTML` as well. Its is not rec-emended to user innerHTML at all. I have used `textContent` which is exactly the same.
`InnerHTML` is not rec-emended officially by javascript MDN . You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML why its not good to use `innerHTML` to change text in elements.

Recreated **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/bv0odyqr/1/

Try this code and should work just fine.

```js
function t5am() {
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  // Year, Month ( 0 for January ), Day, Hour, Minute, Second, , Milliseconds
  //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  //::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
  //::::::::::::              #1                       ::::::::::::
  //::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
  //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  //                                   (AAAA,MM,DD,HH,mm,S));
  var countDownDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 05, 27, 20, 20, 0));

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    const twoHours = new Date();
    twoHours.setHours(twoHours.getHours() + 2);
    var two = twoHours.getTime()


    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    // GMT/UTC Adjustment at the end of the function. 0 = GMT/UTC+0; 1 = GMT/UTC+1.
    var distance = countDownDate - now - (3600000 * 1);

    //Results div
    var result = document.getElementsByClassName("t5am")[0];


    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementsByClassName("t5am")[0].textContent = days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> " +
      minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />";


    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      result.textContent = "Started";
    } else if (distance + twoHours < 0) {
      result.textContent = "Ended";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

t5am()
```

```html
<div class="t5am"></div>
```

Comment: I just modified the code because I had a problem using `GetElementByID`, so I changed it to `GetElementsByClass` and for some reason I can't get your code to work with mine anymore.

Can you help me get it working again?

Comment: @slowdmelendez360 What is the error you are getting when using `className`

Comment: There is no error.
I mean, I needed to show the same function multiple times in my html.
therefore change "ID" to "Class".

The problem is that now I can't get your code to work with the code I just updated

Comment: @slowdmelendez360 I have updated my answer to work with `className` which is `t5am`. Please see the answer updated and run snippet to see it all working.

Comment: Thanks for updating it, but Nope.
It just doesn't change the status from "Started" to "Ended".

Comment: @slowdmelendez360 Here is working fiddle: jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/e6zwpfu7/1 Its applying to all classes just FINE. There is something else wrong in your code somewhere else NOT HERE in this function